# What is the Specific Heat of Molten Bronze?

Tags: thermodynamics, metallurgy, metals

I have sources giving the specific heat capacity of bronze as [382 to 385 J⋅kg⁻¹⋅K⁻¹](https://azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=62), or as [435 J⋅kg⁻¹⋅K⁻¹](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-metal-alloys-d_153.html). I'm assuming the variation is due to different alloys being considered, which are not specified. These sources also do not list the temperatures at which their specific heat values apply, which could be a factor in the variation. However, I am assuming the given values are for solid bronze. Is the specific heat capacity different for molten bronze (say, at 1100 °C)? And if so, how different?

According to Wikipedia, liquid water has a specific heat capacity of 4184 J⋅kg⁻¹⋅K⁻¹ at 20 °C, meaning it requires adding 4184 joules of heat energy to raise the temperature of 1 kilogram of water from 20 °C to 21 °C, or conversely that it requires removing 4184 joules of heat energy to lower the temperature of 1 kilogram of water from 20 °C to 19 °C. Water ice, however, has a specific heat capacity of 2093 J⋅kg⁻¹⋅K⁻¹ just below 0 °C, giving it approximately half the specific heat capacity of liquid water. My research suggests that all materials have different specific heat capacities in different states, but I can't find any sources giving values for molten metals.

Ideally, I'd like to have a graph like this:
[image: Graph of the specific heat capacity of water as a function of temperature.]
([Source](https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/heat/specific-heat-capacity-of-water/))

Comment: Do some research into foundries - they would have to know, also chemistry… but wikipedia is not likely to have detailed info like that. Possibly a place to start for some… But there are always better sources - I usually start with my copy of Geick Tecnical formulae….

Comment: This bulletin has some discussion that may interest you.  https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-the-specific-heat-capacity-of-mild-steel-vary-with-temperature, also this article - https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node18.html

Comment: Water has a tremendous heat capacity.  It is the basis of specific heat calculations.  You may have better luck researching the components of bronze.  [Metals - as Liquids - Boiling points and specific heat of liquid metals](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/liquid-metal-boiling-points-specific-heat-d_1893.html)

Comment: The freezing and vaporizing temperatures are ranges , not specific temperatures ,if that has an affect.